# Sata hotplug doesn't work

Tags: debian, kernel, sata, hot-plug

Can you help me understand, why my SATA hotplug doesn't work? When I plug sata disk, `lsblk` doesn't change. There is only my system disk `/dev/sda`.

I have linux:

```
$ uname -a

Linux Z170-D3H 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.25-1 (2017-05-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Kernel settings:

**$ cat /boot/config-4.9.0-3-amd64 | grep HOTPLUG**

```
CONFIG_MEMORY_HOTPLUG=y
CONFIG_MEMORY_HOTPLUG_SPARSE=y
# CONFIG_MEMORY_HOTPLUG_DEFAULT_ONLINE is not set
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_CPU=y
# CONFIG_BOOTPARAM_HOTPLUG_CPU0 is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_HOTPLUG_CPU0 is not set
CONFIG_ARCH_ENABLE_MEMORY_HOTPLUG=y
CONFIG_ACPI_HOTPLUG_CPU=y
CONFIG_ACPI_HOTPLUG_MEMORY=y
CONFIG_ACPI_HOTPLUG_IOAPIC=y
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_PCIE=y
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI=y
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_ACPI=y
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_ACPI_IBM=m
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_CPCI=y
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_CPCI_ZT5550=m
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_CPCI_GENERIC=m
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_SHPC=m
CONFIG_XEN_BALLOON_MEMORY_HOTPLUG=y
CONFIG_XEN_BALLOON_MEMORY_HOTPLUG_LIMIT=512
# CONFIG_CPU_HOTPLUG_STATE_CONTROL is not set
```

**$ cat /boot/config-4.9.0-3-amd64 | grep SATA**

```
CONFIG_SATA_ZPODD=y
CONFIG_SATA_PMP=y
CONFIG_SATA_AHCI=m
# CONFIG_SATA_AHCI_PLATFORM is not set
# CONFIG_SATA_INIC162X is not set
CONFIG_SATA_ACARD_AHCI=m
CONFIG_SATA_SIL24=m
CONFIG_SATA_QSTOR=m
CONFIG_SATA_SX4=m
# SATA SFF controllers with BMDMA
# CONFIG_SATA_DWC is not set
CONFIG_SATA_MV=m
CONFIG_SATA_NV=m
CONFIG_SATA_PROMISE=m
CONFIG_SATA_SIL=m
CONFIG_SATA_SIS=m
CONFIG_SATA_SVW=m
CONFIG_SATA_ULI=m
CONFIG_SATA_VIA=m
CONFIG_SATA_VITESSE=m
```

**$ cat /boot/config-4.9.0-3-amd64 | grep AHCI**

```
CONFIG_SATA_AHCI=m
# CONFIG_SATA_AHCI_PLATFORM is not set
CONFIG_SATA_ACARD_AHCI=m
```

SATA controller:

```
$ lspci | grep SATA

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
```

Comment: Why should `lsmod` change? The system doesn't load new modules if you hotplug. Use `udevadm` to see if you get the hotplug events.

Comment: @dirkt Thank you and sorry, I meant `lsblk`. Fixed. `udevadm` shows only USB events. When I connect SATA, nothing happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Problem was in wrong BIOS configuration.**

Solution *(for my motherboard Z170-D3H)* is go to **BIOS** > **Peripherals** > **SATA Configuration** and here enable **Hot Plug** option for each SATA port. Then save settings and restart computer.

**Now everything works properly!**

Comment: On my system (ASUS CM6850) you would have to change the SATA mode to AHCI or RAID in order to enable/disable 'Hot plug' mode for each drive. (if it is set to IDE mode, those options will not be available).

Comment: Also switching from IDE to AHCI/RAID mode will make your drive unable to boot (you will have to re-create the drive's partition, etc)